# Add new field in bundle item option in admin section

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6, magento-1.8

I  am new bie in magento.I am creating  a bundle product from admin section .when I add the bundle item there is only the title field for information but I need to add one more field for the description like I created a bundle item for computers but I need to show description about it .

Please help .my requirement is to add new field for description along with the title in bundle item option.
any help  will be appreciated .

Answer (score -1):

you can add extra field to magento bundle products by editing `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\type\select.phtml` and few database changes.

**EDIT:**
first we have to add our custom field to catalog_product_option_type_value table in the database, using a instraller script

```
    <?php

/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer = $this;

$installer->getConnection()

    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('catalog/product_option_type_value'), 'your_custom_field_name’, 'VARCHAR(128) NULL');

$installer->endSetup();
```

then copy the file in location `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\type\select.phtml`

to `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\companyname\catalog\product\edit\options\type\select.phtml.` override the core file

Rewrite: ‘Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select’ block and replace constructor file in it by indicating our phtml file

```
    public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('companyname/catalog/product/edit/options/type/select.phtml');
    $this->setCanEditPrice(true);
    $this->setCanReadPrice(true);
}
```

open `companyname/catalog/product/edit/options/type/select.phtml` ile in OptionTemplateSelect varilable in  tag we add the line: under 'sort order' field

```
'<th class="type-title"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('your_custom_field_name') ?></th>'+
```

Add OptionTemplateSelectRow tag to the variable:

```
'<td><input type="text" class="input-text select-type-details" id="product_option_{{id}}_select_{{select_id}}_title" name="product[options][{{id}}][values][{{select_id}}][your_custom_field_name]" value="{{your_custom_field_name}}">{{checkboxScopeTitle}}</td>'+
```

now check in backend you should see the custom field by now. to make it required you can add required-entry class to above input field

now for retrieve values from database re-write the block:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option
```

In: 'getOptionValues()' method, cycle: foreach ($option->getValues() as $_value) {

add new key: 'your_custom_field_name' to the variable: $value and the value for it: `$_value->getYourCustomField();`

now  custom field will appear in database

In order for the new attribute to appear on the frontend rewrite the class: Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select and add the newly added attribute to it. But be aware that depending on the type of Custom Options there different kinds of htmls generate.

please refer this [article](http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-attributes-custom-options) for more details

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @rgettman When the link is removed, this answer still contains a bit of useful information. It isn't a link-only answer.

Comment: @rgettman thanks guys I have updated the answer though it will hit a copyright issue , anyway i have add essential part of the answer.