# Magento add another new field in bundle item

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I want to add the new text column below the default title of bundle item.
I need to add an extra field when i create a new bundle product
I want the new text field below the default title for adding a description.
please help.Any help will be appreciated.
 [image]

Comment: Pls do not ask same questions twice, you can always edit your original questions (this must your original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087599/add-new-field-in-bundle-item-option-in-admin-section). To community: I could not use flag option from mobile

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar please help me on this problem

Answer (score 4):

In order to add a new `description field` in each `bundle option`, you need to create a module. In short your module is going to do below functionality.

1. Create a new table to save our `description field` for bundle options.
2. When product saves, it will update our table with necessary changes.

With that in mind, let us create our module. Let our module be `Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle`

**Location : `app/code/local/Programmerrkt/Customfieldinbundle/etc/config.xml`**

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle>
</modules>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <programmerrkt_customfieldinbundle>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle</module>
                <frontName>customfieldinbundle</frontName>
            </args>
        </programmerrkt_customfieldinbundle>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <programmerrkt_customfieldinbundle>
                <file>programmerrkt_customfieldinbundle.xml</file>
            </programmerrkt_customfieldinbundle>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <programmerrkt_customfieldinbundle>
                    <class>customfieldinbundle/observer</class>
                    <method>SaveDescriptionAfterProductSave</method>
                </programmerrkt_customfieldinbundle>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_commit_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
<global>
    <models>
        <customfieldinbundle>
            <class>Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>customfieldinbundle_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </customfieldinbundle>
        <customfieldinbundle_mysql4>
            <class>Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <optiondescription>
                    <table>catalog_product_bundle_option_description</table>
                </optiondescription>
            </entities>
        </customfieldinbundle_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <customfieldinbundle_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle</module>
                <class>Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </customfieldinbundle_setup>
        <customfieldinbundle_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </customfieldinbundle_write>
        <customfieldinbundle_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </customfieldinbundle_read>
    </resources>    
    <blocks>
       <!--  need to overwrite a bundle block in order to add additional field -->
        <!-- <bundle>
            <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option>Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option
                </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>  -->
        <programmerrkt_customfieldinbundle>
            <class>Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle_Block</class>
        </programmerrkt_customfieldinbundle>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

Our configuration file contains details about our custom table `catalog_product_bundle_option_description` where we are going to store our bundle description. It also define an observer, which when trigger, will save changes to our custom table.

**Location: `app/etc/modules/Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle.xml`**

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle>
</modules>
</config>
```

Now we need to display our description field in admin side. For that we need to edit a block, that render the bundle options. The block is `app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Bundle/Option.php`. We need to change two methods in this file. **shows only main part

```
<?php
  ----------

/**
* Bundle option renderer class constructor
*
* Sets block template and necessary data
*/
public function __construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('programmerrkt/customfieldinbundle/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml');
    //$this->setTemplate('bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml');
    $this->setCanReadPrice(true);
    $this->setCanEditPrice(true);
}

------

/**
* Retrieve list of bundle product options
*
* @return array
*/
public function getOptions()
{
    if (!$this->_options) {

        $customCollection = Mage::getModel('customfieldinbundle/optiondescription')->getCollection();
        $store_id = $this->getProduct()->getData('store_id');

        //sets default values of description module
        $empty = FALSE;
        if(count($customCollection)){
            $description_id = (int)(count($customCollection)+1);
        }
        else{
            $empty = TRUE;
            $description_id = 1;
        }
        $description_content = "";

        $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->setStoreFilter($this->getProduct()->getStoreId(),
            $this->getProduct());

        $optionCollection = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsCollection($this->getProduct());

        $selectionCollection = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
            $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($this->getProduct()),
            $this->getProduct()
        );

        $this->_options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection);


        foreach ($this->_options as $option) {
                    //gets each option's id
                   $option_id = $option->getData('option_id');
                   //loop through module collection
            if($empty === FALSE){
                   foreach($customCollection as $description){
                        //finds the entry corresponds to option id, if exist
                        if($description['option_id']==$option_id && $description['store_id']==$store_id){
                            $description_id = (int)$description['description_id'];
                            $description_content = $description['description'];
                            break;  
                        }    

                   }
                   //adds our new datas to option
                   $option->addData(array('desc_id'=> $description_id, 'description' => $description_content, 'desc_new'=> 'no'));
            }
            else {              
                    $description_id = (int)$description['description_id'];
                    $description_content = $description['description'];
                    //adds our new datas to option
                   $option->addData(array('desc_id'=> $description_id, 'description' => $description_content,'desc_new'=> 'yes'));
                   $description_id++;

            }
        }


        if ($this->getCanReadPrice() === false) {
            foreach ($this->_options as $option) {
                if ($option->getSelections()) {
                    foreach ($option->getSelections() as $selection) {
                        $selection->setCanReadPrice($this->getCanReadPrice());
                        $selection->setCanEditPrice($this->getCanEditPrice());
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
    }
    return $this->_options;
}

------
```

These methods are

1. `__construct()`

This method is use to define a custom template for option content rendering. Using this we can avoid core template editing.

2. `getOption()`

This method is use to include our module's data to the existiong options. By this method, magento will show set description for the options that are already created.

Now our template file. **shows only main part

**Location: `app/design/adminhtml/<your_package/<your_theme>/programmerrkt/customfieldinbundle/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml`**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
optionTemplate = '<div id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId() ?>_{{index}}"  class="option-box"> ' +
'<input id="description_id" type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>[{{index}}][description_id]" value="{{desc_id}}" />'+
'<input id="description_new" type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>[{{index}}][description_new]" value="{{desc_new}}" />'+
'<div class="option-title"> ' +
    '<label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>[{{index}}][title]"><?php echo Mage::helper('bundle')->__('Default Title') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>' +
    <?php if ($this->isDefaultStore()): ?>
    '<input class="input-text required-entry" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>[{{index}}][title]" id="id_<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>_{{index}}_title" value="{{title}}">' +
    <?php else: ?>
    '<input class="input-text required-entry" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>[{{index}}][default_title]" id="id_<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>_{{index}}_default_title" value="{{default_title}}">' +
    <?php endif; ?>
'<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getOptionDeleteButtonHtml()) ?>' +
'</div>' +


'<div style="margin-top: 10px;font-weight: bold;"> ' +
    '<label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>[{{index}}][description]" style="float:left;"><?php echo Mage::helper('bundle')->__('Default Description') ?> </label>' +
    '<textarea class="input-text" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>[{{index}}][description]" id="id_<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>_{{index}}_description" style="margin-left: 10px;width: 226px;height: 100px;">{{description}}</textarea>' +
'</div>' +


    '<table class="option-header" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">' +
        '<thead>' +
            '<tr>' +
                <?php if (!$this->isDefaultStore()): ?>
                '<th class="opt-title"><?php echo Mage::helper('bundle')->__('Store View Title') ?>  <span class="required">*</span></th>' +
                <?php endif; ?>
                '<th class="opt-type"><?php echo Mage::helper('bundle')->__('Input Type') ?></th>' +
                '<th class="opt-req"><?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape(Mage::helper('bundle')->__('Is Required')) ?></th>' +
                '<th class="opt-order"><?php echo Mage::helper('bundle')->__('Position') ?></th>' +
                '<th>&nbsp;</th>' +
            '</tr>' +
        '</thead>' +
        '<tbody>' +
            '<tr>' +
                '<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId() ?>_id_{{index}}" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>[{{index}}][option_id]" value="{{option_id}}">' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>[{{index}}][delete]" value="" class="delete">' +
                <?php if (!$this->isDefaultStore()): ?>
                '<td><input class="input-text required-entry" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>[{{index}}][title]" id="id_<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>_{{index}}_title_store" value="{{title}}"></td>' +
                <?php endif; ?>
                '<td><?php echo $this->getTypeSelectHtml() ?></td>' +
                '<td><?php echo $this->getRequireSelectHtml() ?></td>' +
                '<td><input class="input-text validate-zero-or-greater" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>[{{index}}][position]" value="{{position}}"></td>' +
                '<td>&nbsp;<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getAddSelectionButtonHtml()) ?></td>' +
            '</tr>' +
        '</tbody>' +
    '</table>' +
    '<div id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId() ?>_search_{{index}}">' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>';
</script>
```

Here what we have done is, we added a text area just below the title field.

Now the most important file. Our observer. This does the trick for our module.It is used to save our data, by checking different criterias.

```
<?php
/**
 * Bundle Products Observer
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle
 * @author      Programmer_RKT
 */
class Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Setting Bundle Items Data to product for father processing
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $observer
     * @return Programmerrkt_Customfieldbundle_Model_Observer
     */
    public function SaveDescriptionAfterProductSave($observer)
    {

        $model = Mage::getModel('customfieldinbundle/optiondescription'); // loads module's model
        $collection =  $model->getCollection();

        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct(); //get current product

        //$optionCollection use to get ids of new options. 
        //$bundleOption does not contain option_id of new option
        //$optionCollection does not contain module's field values. This we can obtain from $bundleOptions
        $optionCollection =  $product->getTypeInstance(TRUE)->getOptionsCollection($product);
        $bundleOptions = $product->getBundleOptionsData(); //@data : array which conatains array
                                                        //get all option data such as title, description, type etc.

        if(!empty($bundleOptions)){
            $store_id = (int)$product->getData('store_id'); //@data : integer

            if($store_id !=0) {
                //if not default store
                foreach ($bundleOptions as $option) {
                    $option_id = (int)$option['option_id'];
                    $description_id = (int)$option['description_id'];
                    $description_new = $option['description_new'];

                    //use to set option_id for new options in our module
                    if($option_id <= 0 || is_null($option_id)){
                        foreach ($optionCollection as $new) {
                            if($new['type'] == $option['type'] && ( $new['title'] == $option['title'] || $new['default_title'] == $option['title'] )){
                                $option_id = $new['option_id'];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $data = array(
                        'option_id' => $option_id,
                        'store_id' => $store_id,
                        'description' => $option['description']
                    );

                   //description id exist means already there is an entry
                    if($description_id >= 0 || $description_new=='no'){
                        $model->load($description_id);
                        $model->addData($data);
                        $model->save();
                    }
                    else{

                        $model->setData($data);
                        $model->save();
                    }

                }
            }

            else {
                //if default store
                foreach ($bundleOptions as $option) {

                    $option_id = (int)$option['option_id'];
                    $description_id = (int)$option['description_id'];
                    $description_new = $option['description_new'];

                    //use to set option_id for new options in our module
                    if($option_id <= 0 || is_null($option_id)){
                        foreach ($optionCollection as $new) {
                            if($new['type'] == $option['type'] && ( $new['title'] == $option['title'] || $new['default_title'] == $option['title'] )){
                                $option_id = $new['option_id'];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $data = array(
                        'option_id' => $option_id,
                        'store_id' => 0,
                        'description' => $option['description']
                    );

                    //description id exist means already there is an entry
                    if($description_id >= 0 || $description_new=='no'){
                        $model->load($description_id);
                        $model->addData($data);
                        $model->save();
                    }
                    else{

                        $model->setData($data);
                        $model->save();
                    }

                }

            }

        }

         return $this;

    }
}
```

Note: I described only the important files of our module. I presume that, you all know how to set up a basic module in Magento.

Thats it. You are ready to go. Clear your cache and load your bundle product. You can see a text area just below the title field of bundle options.

If any enquiry, feel free to ask.

Comment: I set up all of what you said, but I get: `Fatal error: Class 'Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup' not found in C:\wamp2.5\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php on line 234` Please advise.

Comment: @Rajeev K Tomy can you give me full code example for it as there are some file missing like db file etc thanks.

Comment: @Rajeev Why are you adding new table for this purpose? Why dont you add a new column to `catalog_product_bundle_option_value` and reuse existing model triad?